# Is it possible to launch a 2nd url in wedriver in a previously existing browser session?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My testing scenario includes launching a url, entering the cutomer id in that page, which gets stored in the web server and is valid till browser session ends. I have to launch a 2nd url and continue for the same session, but in webdriver launching a 2nd url starts a new session. Can this be handled in Webdriver.

Comment: I believe so, what is the Driver implementation you use (chrome/FF/IE)? Post your non working example if it doesn't work.

Comment: IEDriver and FF driver, but for both when I launch the 2nd url a new browser session starts.

Comment: Can you post your complete case, with the URL used?

Comment: Scenario is like: I have to launch a url, Enter my customer ID and click on submit. Then have to launch the 2nd url in the same browser and continue the application.**Backed functionality is like: When we enter the Customer ID in the 1st url it stores it in webservices and is active till the browser session expires. Using webdriver when I am launching the 2nd url either by using Get or Navigate method, webdriver is launching the 2nd url as a new browser session. My requirement is to run the 2nd url in the previous browser session so that it can fetch the customer ID from the Webservices.

Comment: Cannot share the Url as the url is a restricted one and cannot be accessed outside of my organization.

Comment: Ensure real browsers (without WebDriver) work as expected once URL2 is typed. Also, it could be because URL2 mandates `Referer` header which is sent when URL1 points to URL2.  It would be much better if you have a small web application that fails with WebDriver and you can publicly share.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: With Real browsers its working as expected. Will check if I can get a dummy application with similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use get method as many time you want :)

```java
driver.get("1st_URL");

// perform your business logic and then again use get method

driver.get("2nd_URL"); //again
```

OR you can also use navigate option

```java
driver.navigate().to("2nd_URL");
```

Comment: Both get and navigate command starts a new browser session. It opens the url in the same browser but the browser session is a new one (i.e the response that it sends to the backend server, it sent as a new session)

Comment: @Debabrata Then the problem is with your server code or there is something else you do in how you use Selenium that causes your problem. Selenium does not *by itself* cause the browser to start a new session with each call to `.get()`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open new link with the same session then you should be using `remoteWebDriver`. Here' how you can do it -

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Start you webDriver
driver.get("1st url"); //get url
//Perform operations that you want

//If you are using Firefox use it this way
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:7055/hub"),capabilities); //Now run a RemoteWebdriver
driver.get("2nd url");
```

[More info on remoteWebDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver). Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would you use a completely different driver? You can just do a .get() with the original driver.

Comment: @JeffC, please take a look at the question. It says that getting the url twice starts a new session each time for the user. Please do ask before down voting.

Comment: Thank you Girish for sharing this code. But unfortunately this is also not working. Even with this code when I launch the 2nd Url, the response sent by the 2nd url is as a new browser session.

Comment: Any other way by which this can be handled?

Comment: @Debabrata is it working manually when you try to open new url with the same session? I guess your developer needs to fix the way a session is getting started.